# Ruby on Rails: Load Jquery just before </body> but still make other loaded script work

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, ruby-on-rails-3.2

As we know, load all JS just before `</body>` can make page load faster, so I do this way with my Rails app:
In my layouts/application.html.erb

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>ABC</title>
    <!-- load CSS -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= yield %>
    <!-- asynchronous load Jquery -->
    <!-- asynchronous load others script -->
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem here is in some views, I load some JS stored in `vendor/assets/javascript/` (avoid `//=require_tree .` of assets pipeline), so all of those codes that `<%= yield %>`contain can be loaded before `JQuery` and do not work.

Is there any solution to make all those scripts loaded before `Jquery` work after `Jquery` loaded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [content_for](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-the-content_for-method).

```
# layouts/application.html.erb
<%= yield %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
<%= yield(:custom_js) if content_for?(:custom_js) %>     

# layouts/widgets/show.html.erb
<% content_for :custom_js do %>
  <script src='vendor/assets/javascript/widgets.js'>
<% end %>
```